# Is the intersection of any context free language and the set of all palindromes context free?

Tags: context-free

Let $L$ be any context-free language. Is the set of all palindromes that are elements of $L$
also context-free?

I know that the intersection of context free languages isn't guaranteed to be context free, so I can't apply that here.

I also thought of maybe using the fact that $\{0^{n}1^{n}0^{n}|n ≥ 0\}$ is not context free
as all elements in the set are palindromes, but I don't know what context free language to intersect it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question, and your intuition almost gave you an answer. Simply check the intersection of language $\{0^n 1^n 0^+\,|\,n>0\}$ with the palindrome language :)